# how to change the timestamp format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' to '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S' and do filter in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp

I have the below code.

The first filter_condition1 has timestamp format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

The second filter_condition2 has timestamp format '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S'

Difference between the first and second is H:M:S(Colon) and H.M.S(dot)

Condition2 in the below code is not giving any records.

How can i convert '%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S'  to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'.
Please help

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
mySchema = StructType([StructField("tranid", IntegerType()),                     
                      StructField("trandate", TimestampType()),
                      ])

from datetime import datetime

data = [(1,datetime.strptime('2021-04-20 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
(2,datetime.strptime('2022-05-20 11:01:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
(3,datetime.strptime('2022-06-21 09:02:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
(4,datetime.strptime('2022-06-28 09:55:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
]

df=spark.createDataFrame(data, mySchema)
df.show(3,False)

filter_condition1="trandate > '{}'".format('2021-05-21 09:01:00')
print(filter_condition1)
df.where(filter_condition1).show(3,False)

filter_condition2="trandate > '{}'".format('2021-05-21 09.01.00')
print(filter_condition2)
df.where(filter_condition2).show(3,False)
```

Comment: I tried and your code works...

Comment: filter_condition2="trandate > '{}'".format('2021-05-21 09.01.00')

print(filter_condition2)

df.where(filter_condition2).show(3,False)

this condition is not returning any data

Comment: you can use `strptime().strftime()`

Comment: we can use replace method.
filter_condition2="trandate > '{}'".format('2021-05-21 09.01.00').replace(".",":")

but i am looking for datetime formatter

Comment: @samkart. could  you please help me with the code

Comment: [here's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) a doc on the formatters.

Comment: frankly, I would use `.replace(":",".")` because it is the simples and the fastest.